# How to watch recursive function variables simultaneously in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging in Visual Studio you can see the local variables for the current function that is running in the Locals window. You can also watch specific variables by right clicking them and clicking Add Watch.

However, when watching a variable in a recursive function, it will only show the value for that variable for the latest iteration of the function call the recursion has progressed to.

Is there a way to view the variable contents of each iteration of a recursive function call and have them displayed together in the Local/Watch windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've researched the problem further and found the Parellel Watch functionality within Visual Studio.

While in Debug mode, once hitting a breakpoint you can click

```
Debug > Windows > Parallel Watch
```

Which keeps track of multiple threads open for the watched function, allowing you to select and inspect the local variables for each thread.

[image: ParallelWatch]

[image: Locals]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-parallel-watch-window?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible in Visual Studio. You may consider other ways, such as logging/outputting([Debug.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=net-5.0), [Trace.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline?view=net-5.0)…) the value of variables in the function, or installing some [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=debug&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance) to help log value of variables.